# JMH using java 17, no dead code elimination

Tags: java, jmh

I run sample JHM benchmark which suppose to show dead code elimination. Code is rewritten for conciseness from [jhm github sample](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/blob/master/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_08_DeadCode.java).

```java
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Fork(1)
public class Sample08DeadCode {

    private double x = Math.PI;

    @Benchmark
    public void benchmark() {}

    @Benchmark
    public void measureIncorrect() { Math.log(x); }

    @Benchmark
    public double measureCorrect() { return Math.log(x); }
}
```

Run using JDK 1.8.0_211, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 25.211-b12 produces following results:

```
Benchmark                          Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
Sample08DeadCode.benchmark         avgt    5   0,229 ± 0,018  ns/op
Sample08DeadCode.measureCorrect    avgt    5  12,013 ± 0,047  ns/op
Sample08DeadCode.measureIncorrect  avgt    5   0,228 ± 0,016  ns/op
```

but using java JDK 17.0.2, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.2+8-LTS-86 the results have no sign of dead code elimination:

```
Benchmark                          Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
Sample08DeadCode.benchmark         avgt    5  0,341 ± 0,004  ns/op
Sample08DeadCode.measureCorrect    avgt    5  6,244 ± 0,072  ns/op
Sample08DeadCode.measureIncorrect  avgt    5  6,263 ± 0,094  ns/op
```

Why does the `measureIncorrect()` method is not optimized using java 17?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those samples depend on JDK internals.

Looks like since JDK 9 and [JDK-8152907](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152907), `Math.log` is no longer intrinsified into C2 intermediate representation. Instead, a direct call to a quick LIBM-backed stub is made. This is usually faster for the code that actually uses the result. Notice how `measureCorrect` is faster in JDK 17 output in your case.

But for JMH samples, it limits the the compiler optimizations around the `Math.log`, and dead code / folding samples do not work properly. The fix it to make samples that do not rely on JDK internals without a good reason, and instead use a custom written payload.

This is being done in JMH here:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/CODETOOLS-7903094
- https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/pull/60

Comment: Hi, how is "LIBM" disambiguated?